# Typescript typecasting not working when try to solve: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type X

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have below TypeScript Types:

```
export type ShadowClass = 'left' | 'right';
export type MarginClass = 'leftMargin' | 'rightMargin';

export type StylesProps = ThemeProps & {
  shadowClass: ShadowClass;
  marginClass: MarginClass;
};
```

Then in my React component I have a function to render the correct margin:

```
const renderMargin = ({ marginClass, theme }: StylesProps) => {
  switch (marginClass) {
    case 'leftMargin':
      return `0 0 0  -${theme.spaces.default}`;
    case 'rightMargin':
      return `0 -${theme.spaces.default} 0 0`;
    default:
      return `0`;
  }
};
```

In the CSS part I use this function:

```
  css`
    margin: ${renderMargin((marginClass)};
  `
```

But then I get TypeScript error:

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'StylesProps'.   Type 'string' is not assignable to type
> 'StylesProps'.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ThemeProps'.

I tried to use Typecasting but that doesn't work:

```
  css`
    margin: ${renderMargin((marginClass as MarginClass)};
  `
```

How to solve this Typescript issue?

**Update:**
Solved by adding all arguments to the function:

```
  css`
    margin: ${renderMargin({ marginClass, shadowClass, theme })};
  `
```

Comment: What is marginClassName?

Answer (score 0):

Simple enough: `renderMargin` takes an object of type `StylesProps`, but you are calling it with just a string.

Simply pass an object with all the values:

```
renderMargin({ marginClass, theme })
```

You're not using `shadowClass` in `renderMargin`, so it's not needed to be passed. This suggests you should change the parameter type.
E.g. `({ marginClass, theme }: { marginClass: MarginClass, theme: ThemeProps["theme"] })`

OR

You could change `renderMargin` to be the following:

```
const renderMargin = (marginClass: MarginClass) => {
```

and use `theme` from the surrounding scope.

Comment: Thanks.But how use `theme`in this function, so I am able to use dot notation and typehint from VSCode?

Comment: Where is `theme` defined? Is it imported into to the file where `renderMargin` is defined?

Comment: I solved it see my updated question. Or is there another/better way to solve this?

Comment: Well, where is `theme` coming from?

Comment: `theme` is coming from the `type` StylesProps (ThemeProps)

Comment: I mean, you seem to be able to pass a _variable_ named `theme` to the `renderMargin` function. But nevermind, you seem to have found a solution...